# Controlling subdivision level on sewed cloth

Tags: cloth-simulation, subdivision-surface, multiresolution

I'm using cloth simulation to wrap a pants leg around a collider leg. Sewing works fine but when I add either a subdivision modifier or a multiresolution modifier, the tight sewing gets loose and holey. The problem is that no sewing edges are made between the two cloth pieces.

[image: Two cloth pieces with sewing edges]
[image: Missing sewing edges]

Is there a way to solve this without having to manually connect the two cloth pieces when level of detail is changed?

Comment: I wish it could but from what i know its not possible.